# UV4l HTTPS ssl /etc/UV4l-UVC.conf

Tags: uv4l

I am trying to add https to my conf file. I have made the following changes.

#### HTTPS options:

server-option = --use-ssl=yes
server-option = --ssl-private-key-file=/etc/uv4l/selfsign.key
server-option = --ssl-certificate-file=/etc/uv4l/selfsign.crt

I have created the certificates.

if I comment out the 3 lines above I can access the system through port 8090. When I uncomment them and try to access https://10.1.1.27:8090 I receieve the message in chrome.
This site can’t be reached10.1.1.27 refused to connect.
Search Google for 8090
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Can you please offer any assistane to trouble shoot my issue.
Thanks
Mark